# Watching for Logout in Angular Firebase Authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm using angular Fire (for Firebase Authentication). I've followed a couple of sample codes and starting to build out my authentication flows. One of the sample codes :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  loggedInUser:any = {}
  userid : string = "";
  settings : any = {};
  loggedin:boolean = false;
  public user: IUser;
  public userLoaded:boolean = false;



  constructor(

    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {




    this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log("User Logged In :", {user,uid: user.uid});

          this.db.doc<User>(`Users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(user=> {
            console.log("From Subscription : ", user);


            this.loggedInUser = user;
            this.settings = user.settings;
            this.loggedin = true;

          });



        } else {
          console.log("Assumed Logout", user);

          this.loggedInUser = {};
          this.settings = {};
          this.loggedin = false;
          return of(null)
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();
   }//End of Constructor
```

In this example, I had assumed that I would get a null if the user logs out. However, I'm not finding a way of triggering the else condition within the IF statement.

Is there a way in which I can detect a logout of the application, I'm wanting to do this so that I can clear out any of the variables that I'm holding a key.

For example, in my userService I'm looking to hold a cached copy of the user document from firebase that other I want other services to reference (instead of subscribing to the document directly). I want to make sure that on a logout this is emptied so that a subsequent login doesn't reference the old information.